# How to check if a figure is opened and how to close it?

Tags: matlab

My m-file opens figures depending on parameters. Sometimes is one figure, sometimes it opens 2 figures.

If the user call the function, the figures appear. If he calls the function again, with other parameters, I'm clearing figures with clf before the new plots.

If the second call is set to draw only one figure, the second one (opened by the previous call) remain gray (because of the clf).

Is there any way to check if it is opened and close it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
close all
```

Will close all open figures.

You can use `findobj()` to find objects that may exist by specifying search parameters. For example:

```
figure('name','banana')
```

Creates a figure with the name banana.

```
close(findobj('type','figure','name','orange'))
```

Does nothing because there are no figures open with the name orange.

```
close(findobj('type','figure','name','banana'))
```

Closes the figure.

You can specify search parameters to meet your needs.

Answer (score 14):

I'm a little unclear about what you mean by "open". Figures don't really have "open" or "closed" states. They either exist or they don't. The [FIGURE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure.html) command will return a handle to the figure it makes:

```
hFig = figure(...your arguments here...);
```

You can also get a figure handle from the [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html) function, which will find all graphics objects matching the property values you pass to it:

```
hFig = findobj(...your property/value pairs here...);
```

You can get rid of a figure with either of these commands:

```
close(hFig);
delete(hFig);
```

You can check if a figure has been closed/deleted using the function [ISHANDLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ishandle.html):

```
ishandle(hFig)  %# Returns 'true' if the figure exists, 'false' if it doesn't
```

Figures can also be "visible" or "invisible". They have a [`'Visible'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#Visible) that you can get or set the value of:

```
get(hFig,'Visible')        %# Returns 'on' or 'off'
set(hFig,'Visible','off')  %# Makes a figure invisible, but it still
                           %#   exists (i.e. it's not closed)
```

If you're wanting to check if a figure is minimized, that may be a little more difficult. I believe there are some files that may help you with that on the MathWorks File Exchange: here's [one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3407) to check out.

Comment: Interesting answer, +1. Anywaay I've done it with findobj. Nice to know these things!

Comment: +1 for mentioning "ishandle" - that was the answer I was looking for when google pointed me to this SO question

Comment: That's the answer which I needed, because I wanted to determine it from the figure handle. It's more efficient than first searching for the right object in case one already has the handle.

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB, you can GET information on the 'root'.  Figures are children of 'root' (handle of root is 0)  they are the only children of the root.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-41259.html

Knowing this, you can try this code that looks for the children of root, and gives you a list.

```
>> close all
>> get(0,'children')
ans =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
>> figure(1)
>> get(0,'children')
ans =
     1
>> figure(3)
>> get(0,'children')
ans =
     3
     1
```

I think you will find this the most direct way to query what figures are open.

Answer (score 2):

```
isempty(findobj('name','Your_Figure_Name'))
```

if the answer is 0, then your figure is open

Answer (score 1):

If inside your method, you create a figure without a 'name':

```
function [] = myMethod()
    myFigure = figure()
end
```

you won't be able to access myFigure handle the next time through. So:

```
function [] = myMethod()
    if ishandle(myFigure) % will fault, cant find variable myFigure
        close(myFigure)  % will fault
        delete(myFigure) % will fault
    end

    myFigure = figure()
end
```

gnvoice wasn't 100% clear when he says:

> You can check if a figure has been closed/deleted using the function
>   ISHANDLE:

He means you can only check AFTER you have recovered the handle:

```
function [] = createMyFigure()
    recoveredHandle = findobj('type','figure', 'Name', 'myFigureName')
    close(recoveredHandle)
    delete(recoveredHandle)
    ishandle(recoveredHandle)

    myFigure = figure('Name','myFigureName') % now create figure
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To close figure there is the "close" function. I'm still looking one to check if a figure is open.

Answer (score -1):

```
for f=1:numel(findobj('type','figure'))
    close(figure(f));
end
clear('f')
```